# JavaScript: JSON properties to html content using .forEach

Tags: javascript, json, loops, foreach

My `JSON` data variable is `this.responseText`:

```
{
  'nav': '<a href="">a</a><a href="">b</a>',
  'content': '<div>tartalom</div>',
  'akarmi': 'hello'
}
```

I would like to use `.foreach` loop than:

```
document.getElementById("nav").innerHTML = '<a href="">a</a><a href="">b</a>';
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = '<div>tartalom</div>';
document.getElementById("akarmi").innerHTML = 'hello';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` as follows:

```js
const res = {
  'nav': '<a href="">a</a><a href="">b</a>',
  'content': '<div>tartalom</div>',
  'akarmi': 'hello'
};

Object.entries(res).forEach(([elemId,htmlContent]) => {
  const elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
  if(elem) elem.innerHTML = htmlContent;
});
```

```html
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="akarmi"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but not works. Please see my full code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65984412/14948003

Comment: @jozs2021 this is a separate issue from the question, but it's not a good approach to do this, you'll probably face a ``CORS`` error after the request.

Comment: @jozs2021 good to know you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

It's works! Thanks: JSON.parse()

```
Object.entries(JSON.parse(this.responseText)).forEach(([elemId,htmlContent]) => {
```

Answer (score -1):

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:ajax();">
<div id="nav"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="akarmi"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function ajax () {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            Object.entries(this.responseText).forEach(([elemId,htmlContent]) => {
                const elem = document.getElementById(elemId);
                if(elem) elem.innerHTML = htmlContent;
            });

        }

    };

    xhttp.open ("GET", "foo.php", true);
    xhttp.send ();

}
```

foo.php

```
{
  'nav': '<a href="">a</a><a href="">b</a>',
  'content': '<div>tartalom</div>',
  'akarmi': 'hello'
}
```